# matlab : suppress legend entry without removing from Plot Browser

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

One can suppress a legend entry for a line object `h` by executing `h.HandleVisibility='off'` or `h.Annotation.LegendInformation.IconDisplayStyle='off'`. However, both actions also prevent the curve from appearing in Matlab's Plot Browser user interface, and thus display of the curve cannot be interactively toggled.

Is there any way to suppress a legend entry for a given curve without also removing the ability to toggle display of that curve in the Plot Browser user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's [`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) function accepts an optional argument listing the handles to include in the legend:

```matlab
figure, hold on
h1 = plot(1,1,'ro');
h2 = plot(1,2,'gx');
h3 = plot(2,1,'m*');
legend([h1,h3]);  % don't make a legend for h2.
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if that is the only solution? I am adding line objects in a loop, and have been setting handle/icon visibility based on a condition; therefore, I could instead use that condition to collect within a `gobjects` array only those lines destined to appear in the legend, and then to pass that array to `legend(...)` after plot construction.

Comment: @user001: This is the most convenient solution, and is the one I would use myself. You already had a working solution, but didn't find it convenient. Collecting handles in an array is the way to go in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn off handle visibility. This is way easier than having to set every plot as h1 = ...

Example:

```
x1 = randperm(10);
y = randperm(10);
x2 = randperm(10);

plot(x1, y, '-', 'Color', 'black', 'HandleVisibility', 'off')
hold on
plot(x2, y, '-', 'Color', 'green', 'DisplayName', 'Put This In Legend')
lgd = legend;
set(lgd, 'Location', 'best')
```